# How to remove all but the maximal row corresponding to some value with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with rows such as

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[2001, "Jack", 77], [2005, "Jack", 44], [2001, "Jill", 93]],columns=['Year','Name','Value'])

    Year    Name    Value
0   2001    Jack    77
1   2005    Jack    44
2   2001    Jill    93
```

For each unique `Name`, I would like to keep the row with the largest `Year` value. In the above example I would like to get the table

```
    Year    Name    Value
0   2005    Jack    44
1   2001    Jill    93
```

Can this be done in a simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Name', keep = 'last')
    Year    Name    Value
1   2005    Jack    44
2   2001    Jill    93
```

Writing an edited version just like @piRSquared mentioned.

```
df.sort_values('Year').drop_duplicates(subset = 'Name', keep = 'last')
```

Comment: This is a very good answer but will only work reliably if you sort first. 
 `df.sort_values('Year').drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='last')`  +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**
`groupby` + `nlargest`

```
df.groupby('Name', group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda d: d.nlargest(1, columns='Year'))

   Year  Name  Value
1  2005  Jack     44
2  2001  Jill     93
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.sort_values('Year').groupby('Name',as_index=False).first()
Out[526]: 
   Name  Year  Value
0  Jack  2005     44
1  Jill  2001     93
```