# How to remove the multiindex from GroupBy.apply()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Based off [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46677822/4909087).

> ```
> df = pandas.DataFrame([[2001, "Jack", 77], [2005, "Jack", 44], [2001, "Jill", 93]],columns=['Year','Name','Value'])
>
>     Year    Name    Value
> 0   2001    Jack    77
> 1   2005    Jack    44
> 2   2001    Jill    93
> ```
>
> For each unique Name, I would like to keep the row with the largest
>   Year value. In the above example I would like to get the table
>
> ```
>     Year    Name    Value
> 0   2005    Jack    44
> 1   2001    Jill    93
> ```

I tried solving this question with `groupby` + (`apply`):

```
df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)\
     .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Value').head(1))
     Year  Name  Value
0 0  2001  Jack     44
1 2  2001  Jill     93
```

Not the best approach, but I'm more interested in what is happening, and why. The result has a `MultiIndex` that looks like this:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1], [0, 2]],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 1]])
```

I'm not looking for a workaround. I'm actually more interested to know why this happens, and how I can prevent it without changing my approach.

Comment: `df.groupby(['Name'])[['Year', 'Value']].max().reset_index()`?

Comment: @StefanoPotter Actually, I'm looking to get rid of the max row, apology if my initial answer was misleading.

Comment: Whenever you use apply and the length of the data comes back different than how it started, pandas is going to use the grouping key in the index. Otherwise, if you specify not to use the grouping key, pandas will just glue the data together.  If you specify as index equals false then pandas will just use a factorized version of the grouping keys.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you so much. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IIUC, use `group_keys=False`:

```
df.groupby('Name', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Value').head(1))
```

Output:

```
   Year  Name  Value
1  2005  Jack     44
2  2001  Jill     93
```

Comment: Yes, you understood right. Any idea why the multi index was created and how `group_keys` circumvents it?

Comment: Per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby)," group_keys : boolean, default True
When calling apply, add group keys to index to identify pieces"

Comment: I mean, I kind of know what the docs says, just that I didn't really get it? See if you can explain it in a manner I can follow. :p Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: It appears to be using the group_key as an index level, so in this case 'Jack' and 'Jill' become an added Index level=0 on top of the existing indexes.  However, I will dig into the code and see that for sure in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

use `.reset_index(drop=True)`

```
df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Value').head(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```